# EF6 Code-First Nullable Byte Cast Error?

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 Code-First with my .NET 4.0 project to communicate with a database. One of the columns in the table I am working with is a tinyint that allows NULL values. In my model, I have that column defined as a nulllable byte (byte?). I use LinqPad to test my model. When I try to run a Linq statement where I say Fieldname.HasValue, I get the following error:

"The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int64' type to the 'System.Int16' type is not valid."

Can anyone shed any light as to what is going on?

Comment: I have run into similar cases where `SqlDataReader` does not always read `tinyint` as `byte`

Answer (score 0):

I think the data type of the column inside your database table is Int64 (BIGINT) but your data model has byte?. Either you need to change the data type of underlying table column to TINYINT or change the entity data model property type to long?.

Comment: The data type in the database for the field in question is set to "tinyint", it is not set to "bigint"

Comment: I now realize it was another field entirely that was causing the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson Learned: When you get a "The specified cast from a materialized [type1] to the [type2] is not valid" message, check ALL of your fields, not just the ones you are trying to query on.

My mistake was assuming the error was related to the field that had a nullable byte value. Turns out there was another field I defined as an "int" but the SQL type was "bigint", hence the error.

Thank you to everyone for your patience, your help, and your time.